# is there an R function to find private rows in two data.frames or tables?

Tags: r, intersect

I have two tables f1with dimensions  537 *3 and f2  with dimensions 541 *3
I know that some rows in f2 and f1 are common. how do I find which rows are private to f2 or f1 ?

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join()` will work

Comment: thank you! that's exactly what I was looking for